# Connection reset by <ip> port 22 for all sites

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I have been using Windows 10 PC with OpenSSH to connect to cloud virtual servers. It has been working all these time without problem. Just yesterday I start to have this strange problem.
When I do "ssh support@", it prompts me for password as usual. But after I enter the password, it thinks for about 20 seconds, then gives me "Connection reset by  port 22". And it does this for all the sites I try.
Using a different PC (also with win10 and OpenSSH) I have no problem connect to my cloud server through SSH. Obviously something changed on this particular PC from a few days ago. But I don't know what that could be and how to resolve it. The only thing I can think of is I updated FileZilla on this PC. Could that be it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Some more relevant information. I checked secure log on my cloud server and it shows my password was accepted and an interactive session opened. I don't see any error in the log file. On the client side when I tried ssh -vvv I see some errors such as below,

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
support@<ip>'s password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to <ip> ([ip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: recv - from CB ERROR:10060, io:00000206F94181A0
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: send - WSASend() ERROR:10054, io:00000206F94181A0
Connection reset by <ip> port 22
```

I also found out, on the PC that has trouble connecting, it shows, "OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4". On the PC that doesn't have problem, it is the much older "OpenSSH_3.8.1p1, OpenSSK 0.9.7d". 
I tried installing ubuntu in virtualbox and hoped ssh in ubuntu would work. But it doesn't work either. It seems nothing on this machine would work. But another PC works fine. 
I found similar problem online and the solution is "rebuild OpenSSH to a different location". How can I do that?

Comment: Please use [edit] to add information to the question. not comments.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is finally resolved. Turns out Filezilla was the culprit. After Filezilla was updated again my ssh started working. I will never update Filezilla again. :)

Edit: I spoke too soon. Now my ssh is broken again, without me doing anything I know that  could affect it. First it just hangs after "channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768". Many web posts mentioned this is caused by wifi problem. So I turned off my wifi connection and used wire connection only. Then it gets reset by peer again.

This is driving me crazy. I guess I will wait for the next Filezilla update and hope that will fix my problem.

My final solution is to delete Filezilla and my SSH client started working again. Then I installed older version Filezilla (3.41) and it still works.